# Recalling an expression that was created via a sample

Tags: r

When I want to view structures as they were called, I can usually do it with `enquote`.

For an arbitrary list `d` this would be

```
> d <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
> enquote(d)
# quote(list(a = 1, b = 2))
```

But for an object created via a sample, it's different.  `sample` does not show up in the quoted call.

```
> m <- matrix(sample(2))
> enquote(m)
# quote(c(2L, 1L))
```

Is there a way to show the call/expression that created `m`, so that `sample` shows up? So that the result would be something like

```
quote(matrix(sample(2))
```

---

**Update:** Simon's answer below is great, but I'd really like to see if I can get an answer that doesn't require I use `substitute` to create the matrix `m`.

Comment: I'm not aware of an approach for this task, but, perhaps, for fun you could define an assignment function that stores the call? `"%<-%" <- function(lhs, rhs) assign(deparse(substitute(lhs)), structure(rhs, called_as = match.call()$rhs), envir = parent.frame())`; `x %<-% list(a = 1, b = 2); x`; `x %<-% matrix(sample(2)); x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure if this serves your purpose, but you could try defining an expression with `substitute` before evaluating it to create `m` (no `quote` though...):

```
xpr <- substitute(matrix(sample(2)))
m <- eval(xpr)
```

Result:

```
> m
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    1
> xpr
matrix(sample(2))
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks.  I'd really like to see if I can get an answer that doesn't require I use `substitute` to create `m`.

Comment: How about if you wrote that in your opening question? Might be a little more visible than "hidden" in a comment ;)